# How could I continue this selection pattern?

Tags: edit-mode, edges, selection-tools

[image]

I tried selecting all ring loops and tweak a bit with the checker deselect but this doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: could you please share the object (only the useful part)?

Answer (score 1):

You have an edge ring with several groups of five edges.

You can select the entire edge ring, marking one edge you want to keep as active edge. Then checker deselect with the following options:

- Deselect four consecutive edges
- Select one edge
- Offset the selection of 4 edges

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! On a flat plane it works like you show in the GIF. Unfortunately with the 2 edge loops in the middle it makes for 3 separate edge rings, and the checker deselect doesn't seem to understand the loop direction or something anymore.

Comment: Writing this, I could always change the edit steps ofcourse.

Comment: I've also tested on a circular mesh and it worked. could you upload your blend file?

Comment: ok, I see : this is due to the horizontal cuts, effectively. Maybe you can do it for each horizontal band?